# Operator overloading with vectors: cannot add vector of complex numbers

Tags: rust, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement the `Add` trait for a `Vector` type that I defined.

```
use std::ops::Add;

use num::traits::Float;

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Vector<T>(Vec<T>);

impl<T: Float> Add for Vector<T> {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    fn add(self, w: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let dim = self.0.len();
        let mut t = vec![T::zero(); dim];

        for i in 0..dim {
            t[i] = self.0[i] + w.0[i];
        }

        Vector(t)
    }
}
```

Adding vector of float values works fine.

```
let v = Vector(vec![1., 2., 3.]);
let w = Vector(vec![1., 2., 6.]);

let result = v + w;
println!("{:?}", result);
```

However, when I try to add a vector of complex numbers, it doesn't work. Also, the error is a little vague.

```
let x = Complex::new(1., 3.);
let y = Complex::new(9., -1.);
let z = Complex::new(0.32, 81.);

let v: Vector<Complex<f32>> = Vector(vec![x, y, z]);

// cannot add `vector::Vector<num::Complex<f32>>` to `vector::Vector<num::Complex<f32>>`rustc(E0369)
let result = v + v;
```

Am I missing something about the `Add` implementation? How would I enable the add operation for vector of complex numbers?

Link to code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5d3b0314968fa261287a19be4ad9536

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond! I was looking at the `num-complex` docs and it seems that `num::traits::Float` is implemented by [num::Complex](https://docs.rs/num-complex/0.4.0/src/num_complex/lib.rs.html#163-567), isn't it? Sorry, I'm kinda new to Rust.

Comment: sorry yes, you're right - I was trying to find that in the docs but couldn't, not sure why now! I'll remove my comment as it was incorrect

Comment: @stevenferrer the line you've linked to says: the following methods on `Complex<T>` are only defined when `T` implements `Float` (that is, you can store any pair of `Float` values inside `Complex`). It does not say that `Complex` implements `Float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the reason my code doesn't work is because [num::traits::Float](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Float.html) is not the right type to use. The reason being is that it has too many methods.

To make it work, I defined a trait `Num`, which is "narrower" compared to `Float`.

```
pub trait Num: Add + Zero + Clone + Copy {}
impl<T> Num for T where T: Add + Zero + Clone + Copy {}
```

Then, use that trait instead of `Float`.

```
impl<T: Num> Add for Vector<T> {
    type Output = Vector<T>;

    fn add(self, w: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let dim = self.0.len();
        let mut t = vec![T::zero(); dim];

        for i in 0..dim {
            t[i] = self.0[i] + w.0[i];
        }

        Vector(t)
    }
}
```

With the above change, adding vector of floats and complex numbers now works.

```
// Adding vector of floats works.
let v = Vector(vec![1., 2., 3.]);
let w = Vector(vec![1., 2., 6.]);

let result = v + w;
println!("{:?}", result);

let x = Complex::new(1., 3.);
let y = Complex::new(9., -1.);
let z = Complex::new(0.32, 81.);

let v: Vector<Complex<f32>> = Vector(vec![x, y, z]);
let w: Vector<Complex<f32>> = Vector(vec![x, y, z]);

// Adding vector of complex numbers also works!
let result = v + w;
println!("{:?}", result);
```

On the side note, I'm also implementing other traits (`Sub`, `Div`, `Mul`, etc.) and having a different issue, but that's another thing.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5a2806682331619b2cdbb9202756efc)

Thanks @RobinZigmond and @Dogbert!